# What is unit jω?

Tags: antenna, rfid, physics

I have an equation, from which I'm calculating the induced voltage received by an RFID tag antenna. I know that \$ω\$ = angular velocity, but what is \$jω\$?

And if \$jω\$ is related to angular velocity, what value I should give it, since my system is stationary and there isn't any movement.

Equation of induced voltage at receiver antenna is
$$
V_{ind} = NR_{x} · \mu_0 ·AR_x · jω · H 
$$

Answer (score 4):

`Induced voltage at receiver antenna Vind = NRx · µo ·ARx · jω · H`

The "j" is telling you that the voltage induced is 90 degrees leading the H-field. This ultimately comes from this basic Faraday law: -

$$V = -N\dfrac{d\Phi}{dt}$$

\$\Phi\$ is the magnetic field produced by the H-field.

"j" is what is known as the complex operator. In math circles they use "i" but EEs like to use i to represent current so j is used.

Answer (score 3):

It's just \$j·ω\$. Electrical engineers use \$j\$ to represent the imaginary unit since \$i\$ is already used for currents.

Answer (score 3):

\$ j \omega \$ can also be written \$j \cdot \omega\$ to show that it actually two things multiplied together.

\$j = \sqrt{-1} \$ and thus is unit less. It is an imaginary number and can be thought of as CCW rotation of \$90\$ degrees.  This is useful to simply calculations in passive AC circuits.  In pure mathematics \$ i \$ used in stead but this could be confused with current in electronics.

\$  \omega = 2 \cdot \pi \cdot f \$ the angular frequency measured in \$ \text{rad} \cdot \text{s}^{-1} \$.

Because \$ j \$ is unit less, \$j\omega\$ has units \$ \text{rad} \cdot \text{s}^{-1} \$.